# Total active time of session in PHP

Tags: php, session

I am finding total online time of any user in PHP.

For that purpose, I have calculating difference of user's log-in time and logout time.

But, if any user has log-in to the system and instead of log out, he has closed the browser and shut down his machine.

In such condition, I am finding the existence of file (session id) in session.save_path.

But, here if user's machine is shut down however that file (session id) in session.save_path is present on server.

In such condition, how can I get total online time of that user?

Answer (score -1):

i think its a good idea to put an expiry time limited to what you want 20 min or 30 or day as you like and with each activity of the user you should increase its expiry time

the expiry time is to the cookie of php session
the users last activity time is updated to database

when getting currently online select all those whose last activity is since maximum your time limit [20 min for example]